# Time mentioned during google search

Tags: google-search

What does the time mentioned while google search displays results mean ?  (Eg.  About 1,82,00,00,000 results (0.37 seconds) What does this 0.37 seconds actually mean ?) Does it mean the time to taken to search for the results in the DB ? Or, the time taken to retreive results from the DB ? Or, the time between pressing the Enter key after the query and the display of results ? Or something else. I have searched for answers over the internet but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

This is the time taken by Google’s Query Processor to find the relevant web pages from the Google’s Database in response to your search term.

for more info follow the below link

[https://www.quora.com/What-does-the-number-of-seconds-written-on-a-Google-search-signify](http://Link...)

Answer (score -1):

Its the range of the required search..it depends on the total results of the specified page..

```
  For eg: if you search GOOGLE it shows About 11,01,00,00,000 results (1.25 seconds),GMAIL About 1,06,00,00,000 results (0.63 seconds).
```

According to the loading number of results the ranges differ.

Answer (score -2):

When you search on Google, it shows the number of results found and how quickly it retrieved them. For example, "1,82,00,00,000 results (0.37 seconds)" means about 1.82 billion results were found in 0.37 seconds.